why does the bottom of a 737 - 800 engine look slightly flat?
The 737 - 800 is one of my favorite airliners and so I've always noticed that it's engines look a bit flat on the bottom, I haven't seen any other airliners do this so, is there any specific reason for this?

Image for reference ^ (edited)
https://www.istockphoto.com/es/fotos/boeing-737-800
Source of Image^

The nacelle is oval-shaped because the accessory gearbox, which is usually at the bottom of the fan case, has been moved on the side to increase the ground clearance, as visible in Where is the generator in a large turbofan of a commercial airliner?

The 737 was designed in the 1960s, when high-bypass turbofans didn't exist, so the engines were narrow, but inefficient. It was also designed to use built-in airstairs, for small local airports that don't have any ground stairs or jet bridges. This means the original 737 had to sit close to the ground.



To keep the regulatory advantages of an older design, there are some things Boeing can't change, and one of them is landing gear design. The 737's landing gear is a very simple system that can't be easily made significantly taller.



If you can't make the gear taller, and the engines keep getting larger, both for better efficiency because of the continuous supersizing of the plane - the Max 10 is 90% larger than the -100 Classic - then all that's left is to flatten the nacelle's bottom and/or place the engine forward of the wing rather than under the wing. There has to be some clearance between the engine and the ground, because the wings flex, and any less clearance than on the 737 NG or Max will result in the nacelles occasionally striking the ground on landing.
The -800 uses a flattened nacelle bottom and the MAX does both.

(source)
